# PHP session value via user input from list

Tags: php, session-variables, dropdown

I am working on a php site for my soccer team. The site contains a lot of statistics - i.e. a list of all players who have scored at least one goal. When one of the players visits the site I would like him to be able to choose himself from a dropdown list. When he does that his image emerges and an addclass function happens so his name on the list highlights.

I would like to use the $_SESSION global so the choice from the dropdown list can be used all over the site throughout the session.

---

**Each page will start with:**

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

**My form looks like this:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="highlight">
        <option value="player1">Player 1</option>
        <option value="player2">Player 2</option>
        <option value="player3">Player 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

**My PHP code looks like this:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['highlight'] = $_POST['highlight'];
    }
?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['highlight'];?>
```

I can get the value of the chosen player on the list echo'ed... but how to display his image and how to use the value of the chosen player for highlighting his name on the list?

...and finally (and least important): Can I avoid using a submit button so the click on the player on the list is enough?

Comment: To avoid using a Submit button, you would need a onChange event on your select box that would trigger an AJAX call to the server. Remember, PHP is server-side, you need to talk to the server somehow.

Comment: Thank you Webomatik for the advice regarding the onChange trigger. For the main part of my question I have found another solution why I now close this question. Thank you.